# Retrofit 2: @Query "encoded=false" don't work

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

0) I am using Retrofit 2 for work with [Bank API](https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20170916&json).
1) I have some interface:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("statdirectory/exchange")
    Call<List<MyModel>>  getСurrency(@Query("date") String inputDate);
}
```

2) And when i call method **getСurrency(someParametr)**, where someParametr is string, consist with "date&json" (for example, "20170917&json"):

```
ApiService apiService = RetrofitController.getApi();
apiService.getCurrency("20170917&json").enqueue(new Callback<List<MyModel>>() {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<List<MyModel>> call, Response<List<MyModel>> response) {
          call.request().url();
          Log.e("URL",  call.request().url()+"");
          response.code();
          Log.e("CODE", response.code()+"");      
}
//.....
```

3) I see that:
URL: *"https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20170917**%26**json"* (**&** is replaced by **%26**)
CODE: *"404"*
4) Inmy interface i add **encoded**:

```
getСurrency(@Query(value="date", encoded=false) String inputDate);
```

But *my result is the same as in step 3*!

5) How to check this problem? How to get URL without **%26** on my string? I read other questions with similar problem, but isn't solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: why exactly is this a problem? And why do you have a param `json` without a value?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, my full code is work, but i don't know why my URL _20170917&json_  encode to _20170917%26json_ and how fix it.

Comment: what do you want to fix? Do you even know what url encoding is?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, a little familiar with url encoding. What can I do with this?

Comment: @Tomas you need to build url manually Query won't work as noted in the github issue pointed in my post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2623 by swankjesse

Use [HttpUrl](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html) to build the url

```
HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?date=20170916&json");
```

Then change your method call to

```
@GET
Call<List<MyModel>>  getСurrency(@Url String ur);
```

Then

```
 apiService.getCurrency(url.toString())
       .enqueue(new Callback<List<MyModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MyModel>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<MyModel>> response) {
            // your response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<MyModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

Other way is to use Okhttp's Interceptor and replace %26 by &

```
class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {
   @Override
   Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request()
    String stringurl = request.url().toString()
    stringurl = stringurl.replace("%26", "&")

    Request newRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url(stringurl)
        .build()

    return chain.proceed(newRequest)
 }
}
```

Then

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
 client.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!!! This works for me!) But i have one quеstion... How to use your second way with "Okhttp's Interceptor"? Where i have override `intercept` method?

Answer (score 39):

I just wanted to clarify that the original problem was that the encoded parameter needed to be true: `encoded=`**true**. This indicates that the value provided is already encoded and thus doesn't need to be re-encoded by retrofit. As is stated in the retrofit documentation, the default value of `encoded` is false. ie:

```
getСurrency(@Query(value="date", encoded=true) String inputDate);
```

will result in the correct url being generated.

The documentation states the following regarding the `encoded` parameter:

> Specifies whether the parameter name and value are already URL
>   encoded.

Source: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

Answer (score 2):

If you still got this problem, I have 2 solutions.

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

```
// Create a URL object and pass to constructor your url
URL urlObject = new URL(url);
// Create connection
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
// SET 'GET' request
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
// Create stream to read output
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

// Craete buffer to gain all output
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
AND HERE IS THE KEY
YOU CREATE A BUFFERREADER AND SET CP1251 SO URL`S GONNA BE ENCODED
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "cp1251"));
// Read untill end
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
}
// HERE IS YOUR JSON RESULT
resultJson = stringBuffer.toString();
```

**SECOND SOLUTION:**

Just add `encoded = true` to your `@Query` annotation

```
@GET("some_path")
    Call<RequestBody> function(@Query(value = "param", encoded = true) String your_param);
```

That's it! All that worked well for me. If you have some comments or questions, I will answer them.

Answer (score -1):

your Json will have key value data. Try to pass in below format. 
 It will automatically add the `&` before Json key.

```
getСurrency(@Query("date") String inputDate, @Query("key1") String value1, @Query("key2") String value2);
```