# What is the right way to pass the parameter in the retrofit GET call in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, get, retrofit, rx-java

I wanted to fetch the data from the AWS server in android app and the way I'm using retrofit for this. This part has been resolved.

I wanted to fetch the data with method ONE which is not working.

Please consider that the base URL has no problem `<DOMAIN/>`.

Method ONE:

```
@GET("/release-1a/vendor/getCustomerProfile")
@Headers("Accept-type: application/json")
fun getCustomerProfile(
        @Query("appId") appId: String?,
        @Query("clientId") clientId: String?,
        @Query("clientPhone") clientPhone: String?
): Observable<GetCustomerProfileResponse?>?
```

Network Request

```
CustomerApi customerApi = RetrofitBuilder.getInstance(NEW_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_URL).create(CustomerApi.class);
    Observable<GetCustomerProfileResponse> observable =
            customerApi.getCustomerProfile("4", "5", "%2B919829732808");
```

While using this method I'm getting the error Code 400 which means bad request.
but when I use Method two I got the desired result.

Method TWO:

```
@GET("/release-1a/vendor/getCustomerProfile?appId=4&clientId=5&clientPhone=%2B919829732808")
@Headers("Accept-type: application/json")
fun getCustomerProfile(): Observable<GetCustomerProfileResponse?>?
```

Network Request

```
CustomerApi customerApi = RetrofitBuilder.getInstance(NEW_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_URL).create(CustomerApi.class);
    Observable<GetCustomerProfileResponse> observable =
            customerApi.getCustomerProfile();
```

I see no difference in them. So now I want to know about the correct practice.

Comment: I think some encoding is taking place with %2B, the best way is to see the log on the server (or call local server and see the difference in calls). Have a look at "encoded" parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273510/2842750

Comment: try to intercept the request using Chucker Library to see the full picture

Comment: @PavelBiryukov This solves the issue. I didn't about that.

Comment: Cool! Can I write an answer and you mark it as answer? :)

Comment: @PavelBiryukov sure. Also please make sure to explain the cause of it and why doing `encoding=true` inside Query params resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, the actual value that you're passing to AWS is +919829732808, but "+" cannot be present in URL so it gets encoded as %2B.

You could call:

```
customerApi.getCustomerProfile("4", "5", "+919829732808");
```

But when you call it like:

```
customerApi.getCustomerProfile("4", "5", "%2B919829732808");
```

Retrofit makes additional url encoding (% is replaced with %25) and AWS gets %2B919829732808 instead of +919829732808.
So there are 2 ways - call it with "+" and Retrofit encodes it to %2B or call it with %2B and encoded=true.
Have a look at url encoding description: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP